# Scrum Epics vs MVF

Tags: scrum

If I have an epic with 4 features and one feature isn't really part of another epic but needs to be put into that MVF, do I move the feature to another epic or can epics cross MVF's?

Comment: what does MVF stand for?

Comment: **Minimum Viable Feature.**  Seems like the answer to the question "Can epics cross MVF's" is "No, it wouldn't be desirable to split MVF's this way."   Read https://www.targetprocess.com/blog/2015/02/mvf-mmf-wtf/

Answer (score 4):

Move the feature to where you want it.  Assuming you're doing scrum or something similar, the whole point of the methodology is for your team to be self directed. That means you do what works best for your team.

That being said, an epic can represent work to be done in two or more iterations / sprints (which is what I assume you mean by "MVF"). An epic has nothing to do with when work gets done. An epic is merely a way to organize work conceptually before breaking down the work into smaller stories. You can deliver all of the work for an epic in one iteration, or you can split it among as many as necessary.

The other side of the coin is that because you feel you need to split your epic into different iterations, that may be an indication that your epic is too big. That's much tougher to generalize, because it depends a lot of what your team considers to be an epic, and if you use any other type of concept for the very large parts of the project (ie: can epics be made up of other epics?)

The bottom line is that you need to organize your work in a way that best suits your team. If you spend much time at all worrying about whether you're using the methodology correctly, you're not using the methodology correct. The goal is to complete the work, so do what every gets you closest to that goal.